# Listのセルの色変更

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
List{
Text("テキスト")
.listRowBackground(Color.black)
}
```

で

色が変わりません。

Comment: {Text(pinned[index])}につけると変わりません

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コード自体はあっているので、black以外を試してみて下さい。わかりずらいだけかもしれません。

https://www.motokis-brain.com/article/28

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        List{
            Text("Test1")
                .listRowBackground(Color.red)
            Text("Test2")
                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
            Text("Test3")
                .listRowBackground(Color.green)
            Text("Test4")
                .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
            Text("Test5")
                .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```